# Uno to ESP32 - HardwareSerial repeats value on ESP32's side even though Uno is disconnected

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, esp32, serial-data

I have an Arduino UNO connected to ESP32 through voltage divider with TX0 from Uno to RX2 to ESP32. My goal is to send data from my Uno to my ESP32 through `HardwareSerial`. Here's my code for the Uno:

```
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
int t = 100;
String myString = String(t);
Serial.println(t);
delay(5000);
}
```

Here I assign an `int` to 100 and then cast it to `String` so I can send it on my ESP32's side. My code for ESP32 is:

```
#define RXD2 16
#define TXD2 -1

HardwareSerial Serial2(1); // Use UART channel 1

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial2.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, RXD2, TXD2);
}

void loop() {
if(Serial2.available() >= 1){
Serial.print("Data received:");
Serial.print(Serial2.readString());
}
}
```

The serial monitor on ESP's side is printing only "100" on every 5 seconds but if I disconnect the Uno from my Port, the ESP's monitor keeps printing "100" even tho it shouldn't.
However, **IF** I type `Serial.println("100");` then I get "Data received: 100" on ESP's side and if I unplug the Uno, the ESP's monitor doesn't print anything or with other words it works properly. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: The whole `String` thing is irrelevant. You're not using it. You're printing the integer. Delete the string rubbish.

Comment: you print to Serial. Serial prints to Serial Monitor. on what port is your Serial Monitor listening?

Comment: I'm well aware of that but my goal here is to "pass" a variable to the Serial communication. With the `String` thing, the ESP's side doesn't act properly and that's what I'm trying to fix.

Comment: Uno's port is COM3 and ESP's port is COM4 @Juraj

Comment: the output you see depends on which COM port is in Serial Monitor, not on code changes. the port changes as you change it for upload

Comment: Thank you, I think I fixed my problem now @Juraj